# java llegal base64 character 20 with base64 string from php

Tags: java, php

I generate PDF files with php and return the php file as base64 string like this:

```
$base64 = base64_encode(file_get_contents("http://localhost/pdfgen" . $file));
```

I send the result of this to a java server which should send mails.

but then I got this error:

```
[error] a.a.OneForOneStrategy - Illegal base64 character 20
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 20
        at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Unknown Source)
```

How do I have to encode the pdf file in php that my java service cann consume it.

Thanks in advance

Update:

I call in my ReactJs Frontend via a Post Request the php function which returns a pdf as base64 encoded string. That looks like above.

In my frontend I send again a post to a java backend which is responsible for the mail service.

UPDATE Mail function:

```
package scheduler

import java.util.Base64

import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorRef, ActorSystem}
import dto.email.models._
import dto.email.{emailDTO, emailLogDTO, smtpServerDTO}
import javax.inject.{Inject, Named}
import javax.mail.Message.RecipientType
import org.codemonkey.simplejavamail.{Email, MailException, Mailer, TransportStrategy}
import play.api.Configuration

import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.util.Random

object EmailSendActor {

  case class Start(id: Int)

  trait Factory {
    def apply(): Actor
  }

}

class EmailSendActor @Inject()(
  implicit val executionContext: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext,
  implicit val emailDTO: emailDTO,
  implicit val emailLogDTO: emailLogDTO,
  implicit val smtpServerDTO: smtpServerDTO,
  configuration: Configuration,
  val system: ActorSystem, @Named("email-send-scheduler") val schedulerActor: ActorRef
) extends Actor {

  import EmailSendActor._

  private val retryDelay = configuration.get[Int](EmailSchedulerActor.retryDelayKey)
  private val idlePause = configuration.get[Boolean](EmailSchedulerActor.idlePauseKey)
  private val simulateFailures = configuration.get[Boolean](EmailSchedulerActor.simulateFailuresKey)

  def receive: PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = {
    case x: Start =>
      println("Email Sender Running")
      schedulerActor ! EmailSchedulerActor.Busy(x.id)
      var emailCount = 0
      var retry = false

      val smtpServer = Await.result(smtpServerDTO.getGlobal, Duration.Inf)
      if (smtpServer.isDefined) {
        val globalSmtpServer = smtpServer.get

        println("Got Global Smtp Server " + globalSmtpServer)

        val result = emailDTO.getEmailsToSend(globalSmtpServer.smtpServerTypeId, retryDelay).map(emails => {
          emails.foreach { email =>
            emailCount += 1
            if (email.emailStatusTypeId == EmailStatusTypes.pending) {
              println("Sending new email[" + email.emailId + "]: " + email.recipients + ": " + email.subject)
              if (tryToSendEmail(globalSmtpServer, email)) retry = true
            } else if (email.emailStatusTypeId == EmailStatusTypes.retrying) {
              println("Retrying to send email[" + email.emailId + "]: " + email.recipients + ": " + email.subject)
              if (tryToSendEmail(globalSmtpServer, email)) retry = true
            }
          }
        })

        Await.result(result, Duration.Inf)
        if (emailCount > 0) {
          println("Done sending " + emailCount + " e-mails")
        } else {
          println("No e-mails to send")
        }
      } else {
        println("No Global Smtp Server Configurations, idling")
      }

      // reschedule next run
      if (retry) {
        schedulerActor ! EmailSchedulerActor.Retry(x.id)
      } else if (!idlePause || emailCount > 0) {
        schedulerActor ! EmailSchedulerActor.Done(x.id)
      } else {
        schedulerActor ! EmailSchedulerActor.Pause(x.id)
      }
  }

  private def tryToSendEmail(smtpServer: SmtpServerModel, email: EmailModel) = {
    var retry = false

    val sendResult = if (simulateFailures) Random.nextInt(5) else 0

    val result: (Future[Int], Future[Int]) = sendResult match {
      case 1 => // retry
        println("retrying")
        retry = true
        (emailDTO.updateEmailStatus(email.emailId.get, EmailStatusTypes.retrying),
          emailLogDTO.create(EmailLogModel(
            emailStatusTypeId = EmailStatusTypes.retrying,
            smtpServerId = smtpServer.smtpServerId.get,
            emailId = email.emailId.get,
            statusMessage = Option("Retrying")
          )))

      case 2 => // failed
        val status = Random.nextInt(EmailStatusTypes.retryTimeout - EmailStatusTypes.unknownDestination) + EmailStatusTypes.unknownDestination
        println("failed, status: " + status)
        (emailDTO.updateEmailStatus(email.emailId.get, status),
          emailLogDTO.create(EmailLogModel(
            emailStatusTypeId = status,
            smtpServerId = smtpServer.smtpServerId.get,
            emailId = email.emailId.get,
            statusMessage = Option("Failed randomly")
          )))

      case _ => // success
        val sendEmail = new Email()
        sendEmail.setFromAddress(smtpServer.fromName, smtpServer.fromEmail)
        sendEmail.setSubject(email.subject)

        val recipients: Option[Seq[EmailRecipient]] = EmailApi.getRecipients(email.recipients)
        if (recipients.isDefined) {
          recipients.get.foreach({ recipient =>
            sendEmail.addRecipient(recipient.name, recipient.email, RecipientType.TO)
          })
        }

        val ccRecipients: Option[Seq[EmailRecipient]] = EmailApi.getRecipients(email.ccRecipients)
        if (ccRecipients.isDefined) {
          ccRecipients.get.foreach({ recipient =>
            sendEmail.addRecipient(recipient.name, recipient.email, RecipientType.CC)
          })
        }

        val bccRecipients: Option[Seq[EmailRecipient]] = EmailApi.getRecipients(email.bccRecipients)
        if (bccRecipients.isDefined) {
          bccRecipients.get.foreach({ recipient =>
            sendEmail.addRecipient(recipient.name, recipient.email, RecipientType.BCC)
          })
        }

        var emailStatusTypeId = EmailStatusTypes.sent
        var statusMessage = "Sent"

        if (sendEmail.getRecipients.isEmpty) {
          emailStatusTypeId = EmailStatusTypes.unknownRecipient
          statusMessage = "No recipients"
        } else {
          if (email.isHtml.get) sendEmail.setTextHTML(email.body)
          else sendEmail.setText(email.body)

          if (!email.attachments.isEmpty) {
            val attachments: Option[Seq[EmailAttachment]] = EmailApi.getAttachments(email.attachments)
            if (attachments.isDefined) {
              attachments.get.foreach(attachment => {
                val bytes = Base64.getDecoder.decode(attachment.base64Content)
                sendEmail.addAttachment(attachment.name, bytes, attachment.mimeType)
              })
            }
          }

          try {
            new Mailer(smtpServer.address, smtpServer.port, smtpServer.username, smtpServer.password, smtpServer.smtpEncryptionTypeId match {
              case SmtpEncryptionTypes.none => TransportStrategy.SMTP_PLAIN
              case SmtpEncryptionTypes.ssl => TransportStrategy.SMTP_SSL
              case SmtpEncryptionTypes.tls => TransportStrategy.SMTP_TLS
            }).sendMail(sendEmail)

            println("email sent")
          } catch {
            case t: Throwable =>
              statusMessage = t.getMessage
              println(s"Send Failed with message $statusMessage")

              t match {
                case e: MailException =>
                  emailStatusTypeId = statusMessage match {
                    case OpenMailException.GENERIC_ERROR => EmailStatusTypes.serverError
                    case OpenMailException.MISSING_HOST => EmailStatusTypes.serverError
                    case OpenMailException.MISSING_USERNAME => EmailStatusTypes.unknownRecipient
                    case OpenMailException.INVALID_ENCODING => EmailStatusTypes.serverError
                    case OpenMailException.INVALID_RECIPIENT => EmailStatusTypes.unknownRecipient
                    case OpenMailException.INVALID_REPLYTO => EmailStatusTypes.serverError
                    case OpenMailException.INVALID_SENDER => EmailStatusTypes.serverError
                    case OpenMailException.MISSING_SENDER => EmailStatusTypes.serverError
                    case OpenMailException.MISSING_RECIPIENT => EmailStatusTypes.unknownDestination
                    case OpenMailException.MISSING_SUBJECT => EmailStatusTypes.serverError
                    case OpenMailException.MISSING_CONTENT => EmailStatusTypes.serverError
                    case _ => EmailStatusTypes.serverError
                  }

                case _ => EmailStatusTypes.serverError
              }
          }
        }

        (emailDTO.updateEmailStatus(email.emailId.get, emailStatusTypeId),
          emailLogDTO.create(EmailLogModel(
            emailStatusTypeId = emailStatusTypeId,
            smtpServerId = smtpServer.smtpServerId.get,
            emailId = email.emailId.get,
            statusMessage = Option(statusMessage)
          )))
    }

    Await.result(result._1, Duration.Inf)
    Await.result(result._2, Duration.Inf)
    retry
  }
}
```

error is in this line:

```
val bytes = Base64.getDecoder.decode(attachment.base64Content)
```

Comment: `20` is ASCII code of whitespace. Make sure you receive you string exactly how you generated it in php, without any surrounding whitespaces.

Comment: I don't have surrounding whitespaces. But in The string are lots of 'Y20' and '20'

Comment: it would help if you showed how you send it to the Java server, and how the Java server tries to read it. Some sample data which reproduces the error would also be very helpful. It's unclear how you ended up with a base64 string with spaces in it. Perhaps you forgot to URL-encode the string or something in before transmitting? We can't be sure without seeing code and data.

Comment: P.S you said _"in The string are lots of 'Y20' and '20'"_ we are not talking about the literal character 20...we're talking about the ASCII (hex) character code for a space. https://www.sciencebuddies.org/science-fair-projects/references/table-of-8-bit-ascii-character-codes

Comment: can I avoid this by generating the base64 string?

Comment: You can use Base64.getMimeDecoder() instead of Base64.getDecoder()

Comment: `base64_encode()` create a long basa64 string, and mail agents split long lines into smaller ones. base 64 allows line breaks, but only every 4-th char. Wrong broken lines result in errors. If you show the send mail. we can confirm it.

Comment: Now you've given a clearer description of the scenario...why are you bothering to base64-encode the file? Why not just send the file directly?

Comment: the mail api I use only accepts the file as base64 string.

Comment: Now I return the pdf as string to the frontend. And use this: https://stackabuse.com/encoding-and-decoding-base64-strings-in-node-js/ to encode it as base64.

No I got a PDF with correct page size. and it can be opened. But the pages are all white

Comment: @Wiimm added the mail function above

Comment: okay there are symbols at the beginning of my string. `"base64Content":"  JVBERi0xLjQ`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with:

```
pdf.trim()
```

Now I have a valid base64 and all works fine.